# Silence after calling a twilio number

Tags: twilio

About 20% of the time what I get after calling my twilio number is just pure silence - nothing happens. I know I am connected because iphone starts counting time. The number is configured to open a incoming-call.php on my serever and play a mp3 file (but not a long one - 3 sec). Could this be because twilio can't connect to my server?

Comment: It could be because Twilio is loading the mp3. Twilio will cache the mp3 according to its cache headers. If the mp3 doesn't change, you can set a long expiry so this loading doesn't occur. Can you check your server logs to see whether the request from Twilio is getting through?